# Permission/Role/Task Required to Get Comment Counts in Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I'm trying to access comment counts as part of my analysis on facebook page post engagement. While I can make my code work in a page where I have admin access, I can't in another page. It would have been easier if the comment count is part of /insight. So my question is, what specific credentials/permissions do I need in order to get the comment count. Not the comments, just the count.

Comment: _"It would have been easier if the comment count is part of /insight"_ - without admin access, you would not get any insights either.

Comment: You will need https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/page-public-content-access for this.

Comment: thanks for the reply @CBroe. I don't necessarily need administrator access for /insight since an Analyze role would suffice for that but it's different for comment counts.